# Unique indexes couldn't be exported to database by entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, mysql-workbench

I modeled a database with primary keys, foreign keys and unique indexes by using MySQL Workbench. I synchronized my model file with MySQL database and then created a console project in Visual Studio 2012. After that, i added a data entity model with an existing database. There is no problem. To understand if does entity framework create database successfully, i deleted the database. Then i ran the console program, database created successfully but unique indexes couldn't be exported to db. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't support unique keys. Unique keys are not used in the model and because of that it also doesn't create them when creating database from model. The only exception is manual creation of unique keys either through custom database intializer or migration (both are used in code-first approach).